# How do I create multiple views in the same query in SQL and then join them?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is the query that I am using.
I need to join the three views to calculate the monthly total revenue.
How should I proceed?

```
With Txn as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval 330 MINUTE), '%y-%m') as Month, Sum(netPrice/100) as TransactionRevenue from transactions 
group by Month)

With Leaves as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval -1 MONTH), '%y-%m') as Month, sum(amount/100) as LeaveRevenue from driverPaymentTransactions
group by Month)

With Sxn as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval 330 MINUTE ), '%y-%m') as Month, sum(amount/100) as SubscribedRevenue from subscribedDriversDailyRevenues
group by MONTH) 

Select * from Txn t
join Leaves l on t.Month = l.month
join Sxn s on t.month = s.month
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "join" the subqueries

```
CREATE VIEw myview 
AS (With Txn as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval 330 MINUTE), '%y-%m') as Month, Sum(netPrice/100) as TransactionRevenue from transactions 
group by Month)
, Leaves as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval -1 MONTH), '%y-%m') as Month, sum(amount/100) as LeaveRevenue from driverPaymentTransactions
group by Month)
, Sxn as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval 330 MINUTE ), '%y-%m') as Month, sum(amount/100) as SubscribedRevenue from subscribedDriversDailyRevenues
group by MONTH) 

Select * from Txn t
join Leaves l on t.Month = l.month
join Sxn s on t.month = s.month)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
With Txn as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval 330 MINUTE), '%y-%m') as Month, Sum(netPrice/100) as TransactionRevenue from transactions 
group by Month),
Leaves as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval -1 MONTH), '%y-%m') as Month, sum(amount/100) as LeaveRevenue from driverPaymentTransactions
group by Month),
Sxn as(
Select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(createdAt, interval 330 MINUTE ), '%y-%m') as Month, sum(amount/100) as SubscribedRevenue from subscribedDriversDailyRevenues
group by MONTH) 
Select * from Txn t
join Leaves l on t.Month = l.month
join Sxn s on t.month = s.month
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was missing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do not join when you need to "pull" some different measures to the common attribute. Use `union all`, where you do not need to care about the most complete source of group values:

> ```
> create table t1 as
> select 1 as id, 10 as val union all
> select 1, 20 union all
> select 2, 30 union all
> select 3, 49
> ```

> ```
> create table t2 as
> select 1 as id, 10 as val union all
> select 3, 20 union all
> select 3, 30 union all
> select 5, 49
> ```

> ```
> create table t3 as
> select 4 as id, 10 as val union all
> select 6, 20 union all
> select 2, 30 union all
> select 3, 49
> ```

> ```
> with u as (
>   select
>     id
>     , val as t1_val
>     , cast(null as decimal) as t2_val
>     , cast(null as decimal) as t3_val
>   from t1
>
>   union all
>
>   select
>     id
>     , null as t1_val
>     , val as t2_val
>     , null as t3_val
>   from t2
>
>   union all
>
>   select
>     id
>     , null as t1_val
>     , null as t2_val
>     , val as t3_val
>   from t3
> )
> select
>   id
>   , sum(t1_val) as t1_val
>   , sum(t2_val) as t2_val
>   , sum(t3_val) as t3_val
> from u
> group by id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | t1_val | t2_val | t3_val
> -: | -----: | -----: | -----:
>  1 |     30 |     10 |   null
>  2 |     30 |   null |     30
>  3 |     49 |     50 |     49
>  5 |   null |     49 |   null
>  4 |   null |   null |     10
>  6 |   null |   null |     20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1037975ca39d0f4b02ebb8cea86c7d56)*